# Hello, I have an app on Amazon and want to host on my domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have a fairly simple question, but I can't have this working out. I have an app hosted on amazon, which is my ip/app. Ex: 111.111.111/app.
I have my domain on dreamhost.
I want my app to be app.mydomain.com, I've redirected on dreamhost to my app, but, when it redirect, it does not show my domain but my ip/app. How can I do this?

Comment: I would look into AWS Route 53. It's the primary way of handling DNS for apps hosted on AWS.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How redirect a domain to Amazon EC2 Machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554156/how-redirect-a-domain-to-amazon-ec2-machine)